# MySQL get time when rows is not in specific state

Tags: mysql

I have issues solving a MySQL statement.
The rows looks like this:

```
Running 2016-04-12 12:00:30
Running 2016-04-12 12:01:50
Running 2016-04-12 12:02:40
Stopped 2016-04-12 12:03:20
Preparing 2016-04-12 12:03:30
Stopped 2016-04-12 12:04:10
Starting 2016-04-12 12:04:40
Running 2016-04-12 12:05:30
Running 2016-04-12 12:06:20
Stopped 2016-04-12 12:07:50
Stopped 2016-04-12 12:08:10
Preparing 2016-04-12 12:03:30
Running 2016-04-12 12:09:50
Running 2016-04-12 12:10:10
```

Im trying to get the total time that the state is not "Running". I honestly don't know where to start on this one, all guidance is appreciated!

Comment: is it running at 12:04:00 or not? because there are 2 stopped time around that time

Comment: The rows are loggs so it can be multiple stopped rows following each other if its a long stop. I think that a stop can be defined as the time between the last and first "Running" for example 12:05:30-12:02:40= 00:02:50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `timestampdiff` and `user variable`.

***SQLFiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/971cd/1***

### Needed query:

```
select sum(stop_seconds) as total_stop_seconds
from (
    select 
        if(status = 'Running' and @last_status = 'Stopped',
           timestampdiff(second, @last_dt, dt),
           0) as stop_seconds,
        @last_status := status,
        @last_dt := dt
    from t1 cross join (select @last_status := NULL, @last_dt := NULL) param
) t2;
```

### Output:

```
+--------------------+
| total_stop_seconds |
+--------------------+
|                180 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I realize that i was unclear in my example data but i need the query to be able to get the time between "Running" state, there can be other states than "Stopped" in between. For example "Preparing", the only state i can be sure to see is the "Running" states surrounding the other states.

Comment: I ended using something as simple as: "if(@last_status <> 'Printing', timestampdiff(" and it works great! :D

Answer (score 0):

if you define stopped time as time between the last and first "Running" for example 12:05:30-12:02:40= 00:02:50.
Then you can use something like this query.

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,stoptime,starttime)) as stoppedtime
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT stoptime,starttime 
      FROM
      (SELECT state, at,
            (SELECT MAX(at) FROM Test T2 WHERE state = 'Running' AND T2.at < T1.at) as stoptime,
            (SELECT MIN(at) FROM Test T3 WHERE state = 'Running' AND T3.at > T1.at) as starttime
      FROM Test T1
      WHERE state = 'Stopped')T4
 )T5
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i went with Dylan Su's solution